# overdue library book query: is dateDueBack < todaysDate

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, where-clause

I'm trying to extract a list of all the overdue items from my library database.

How would I express this in SQL?

```
SELECT * from items WHERE dateDueBack "is before today's date"
```

```
itemId dateDueBack 
1      2020/04/01
2      2019/03/22
3      2018/05/24
```

Comment: please tag with the appropriate database platform and show the table definition with the data types of each columns.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

mysql - `SELECT * from items WHERE dateDueBack < NOW();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current_date`, which gives you today's date, without the time component:

```
select * from items where datedueback < current_date
```

This assumes that `datedueback` is of a date-like datatype (`date`, `datetime`, `timestamp`).